# SVG Shapes and Text Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, text, svg, drag-and-drop, rectangles

I am trying to make an SVG shape with text draggable, and although I made it draggeble the text remains a separate entity from the shape. Can the text and the shape be made one so that I can drag them together?

Thank you in advance.

SG

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, make both the text and the shape children of a `<g>` element and make the `<g>` draggable. You'll probably want to make the text and shapes in the `<g>` pointer-events="none" so that all mouse events go to the `<g>`.